# ¿Cómo mostrar el valor seleccionado de un Combo Box en un Label?

Tags: c#

La linea que me arroja error es:

```
lbltipo.Text=cbtipo.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Me provoca el siguiente error:

> Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de objeto

El punto de este es que cada vez que seleccione un valor en el `Combo Box` se cambie el `Label` y el color también.

Estoy trabajando en el evento `SelectedIndexchanged`, **¿es el correcto?**

Ese es el formulario, no tengo más código, empieza por esa parte. El combo debajo del "seleccione el tipo" es que quiero utilizar para cambiar los espacios en blancos entre unos label que hay debajo del `datagridview` (los `Label` están ahí solo que no tienen valor puse "puse tipo en uno para que vean donde están").

Comment: ¿Cada opción del combo tiene asignado un valor? ¿Si lo pruebas con cbtipo.SelectedText te funciona? Es por descartar

Comment: mi combo ya tiene valores solo es seleccionar el que desee y hay unos label que tienen que cambiar segun lo que seleccione en el combo... probe con selectedtext y no me funciono

Comment: Si estás usando VisualStudio puedes poner un punto de interrupción en esa linea, y ver que vale SelectedValue en ese punto. El error que te está dando es o porque el label o el selectedvalue están a nulos.

Comment: Tienes que poner mas código, de esa forma es imposible darte la ayuda necesaria, es como que yo te pusiera ¿Porque no me muestra mi cadena? y pongo de codigo `Console.WriteLine(micadena);` y no doy mas información.

Comment: @aenon83 si estan vacios osea sin letras para cuando carge el formulario este ahi pero sin nada mostrando , para cuando seleccione en mi combo se escriba lo mismo que seleccione en el combo

Comment: @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver es que estoy comenzando a hacer el formulario no tengo mas nada que mostrar osea para hacer eso creo que no necesito conexion a base de datos.

Comment: @SamuelIgnacioSusanaConfesor ¿Podrías poner algo más de código como te han comentado? Y cuando te salta el error, ¿nada más cargar el formulario? ¿cuándo has seleccionado el valor?

Comment: @aenon83 edite la publicacion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tu primer problema** está en el uso del método `.ToString` de la propiedad `SelectedValue`.

La misma te está retornando `Null`, y el error

> **"Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de objeto"**

Es provocado porque el método `.ToString` **no permite Nulls.**

**Tu segundo problema** puede estar en el uso de la propiedad `SelectedValue`, ya que, la propiedad por la que deberías **reemplazarla es `SelectedItem`**.

La diferencia entre las dos tiene que ver con los orígenes de datos, es decir, como cargas los datos y donde están referenciados. Más información: [ComboBox SelectedItem vs SelectedValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883481/combobox-selecteditem-vs-selectedvalue), [Difference between SelectedItem & SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902039/difference-between-selecteditem-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath)

Para solucionarlos puedes adaptar el código de la siguiente manera:

```
private void cbtipo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     lbltipo.Text = Convert.ToString(cbtipo.SelectedItem);
}
```

**Aclaración:**

Utilizando el método `.ToString` pero de la Clase `Convert` que **si acepta Nulls**.

Hace poco (lo busqué pero no lo encontré) había leído una respuesta en SOes sobre la diferencia de utilizar `Convert.ToString`, `.ToString`, y de esa respuesta es que sale esta última aclaración.

Comment: tu metodo no me da error pero no muestra la seleccion en el label osea selecciono algo del combo y el label no lo muestra

Comment: Perfecto Samuel, entonces debes analizar en dónde estás colocando el código. **¿En qué evento estás ejecutándolo?** Si es en el SelectionIndexChanged, como dices en la pregunta, debería de funcionar.

Comment: selectedindexchanged

Comment: Acabo de editar mi respuesta con lo que puede ser la solución a tu problema.

Comment: ya la vi me funciono muchas gracias , para poder asignarle un color a ese label puedo utilizar este codigo: myLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;? en la misma linea o otra=

Comment: En el mismo procedimiento, luego de esa linea, puedes aplicar tal como dices la linea para convertir el color del Label. Confirmame si estás trabajando en `wpf` para que añadamos la etiqueta a la pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Yo trabajo bajo este evento.

```
  private void cmb_tipo_busqueda_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {

                    if (cmb_tipo_busqueda.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Maquina")
                    {

                    }

                }
```

Ahora porque lo hago así... yo consulto en la bd las opciones y le cargo 2 `Array` un `displayMenber` que será lo que se mostrará y `ValueMenber` que serán los valores de esos datos, ejemplo yo puedo seleccionar Maquina 1 pero el código será:

```
Maq-1
```

Entonces debe probar mostrando en:

```
Messagebox.show(cmb_tipo_busqueda.SelectedValue.ToString())
// o talvez 
Messagebox.show(cmb_tipo_busqueda.SelectedItem.ToString())

// o talvez en el caso que uses el valueMember
Messagebox.show(cmb_tipo_busqueda.SelectedValuePath.ToString())
```

Has pruebas para ver cual no te bota error.

Comment: esta bien probare

Comment: como te fue haciendo las pruebas?

Comment: si me funciono gracias tambien

Answer (score 1):

También puedes **castear** el valor a `string`.

```
lbltipo.Text= (string)cbtipo.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: gracias  Agustin M. por la correccion, fue por estar de rapido jeje... :v

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiar el color del label es tan sencillo como:

```
myLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

Comment: gracias por el codigo

Answer (score 0):

Espero no llegar tarde!! o que les sirva de referencia...

```
private void cbtipo_SelectedIndexChanged ( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
       if (cbtipo.Text != "")
       {
          Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
          lblPrueba.Text = cbtipo.Text;

          switch (lblPrueba .Text )
            {
              case "Maquina": lblPrueba.ForeColor = Color.Red;
               break; 
              case "Bisicleta": lblPrueba.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
                break;
            } 
          Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
       }
    }
```